# Proper bending of trace in high frequency coupler question

Tags: shielding, trace

A coupler 32-38 GHz was designed. I need to bend the legs in an optimal way so I won't get reflections.
My bend is 45 degrees. Is there a logic I could use to find the optimal distance of the bended leg an the coupler?
maybe the the legs input leg has some logic too I need to use? 
Thanks.

[image]

[image]